# Application to transfer music, photos, data to android phone?

Tags: software-recommendation, android

is there is any application in software center to  connect android phone to Ubuntu for connectivity just like [mobogenie](http://www.mobogenie.com/) for windows

Comment: Goes beyond file transfer and into device management, so not a duplicate IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

[Airdroid](http://airdroid.com/) is a [universal](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/12/airdroid-manage-your-android-device.html), [OS-agnostic solution](http://fitzcarraldoblog.wordpress.com/2012/10/25/airdroid-a-handy-android-app-for-managing-your-phone-from-linux/).

Beyond that, there's a [procedure for SSH access](http://www.maketecheasier.com/access-android-device-with-linux-file-managers/) and a nice article which explains how to use [Dropsync](http://www.maketecheasier.com/access-android-device-with-linux-file-managers/).

Answer (score 0):

I actually set my Android using MSC method to connect to Ubuntu. It can access my android device memory card (my Android device has micro SD card slot with micro SD card inserted to the device) . Ubuntu can recognize the micro SD card (yes, your android act as a card reader in MSC method) and mount it automatically. You can set this in your Android device (locate in USB connectivity settings)

So far, Android actually use internal memory to store some important data like contacts, and you can only access it using MTP method, which, to what I know, only Windows supports that type of USB connections.

There's another, perhaps an alternative, is to use Cloud service, or use Google Sync to do synchronization (of course over the internet).